# How to use NVL/DECODE correcly?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below query (Oracle) that needs to be corrected :

```
select
   parm_data_1,
   parm_data_2,
   parm_data_3,
   parm_data_4,
   parm_data_5,
   parm_data_6,
   parm_data_7,
   parm_data_8,
   parm_data_9,
   parm_data_10,
   parm_data_11,
   parm_data_12,
   parm_data_13,
   parm_data_14,
   parm_data_15,
   parm_data_16,
   parm_data_17,
   parm_data_18,
   parm_data_19,
   parm_data_20,
   wild_card_ind
--  End SIR A3109
from dbt_c_param_data
where
parm_id = i_param_id and

    brch_code  in ( nvl(i_pdet(1),'*'), '*') and
    prod_code  in ( nvl(i_pdet(2),'*'), '*') and
    cus_mst_no in ( nvl(i_pdet(3),'*'), '*')  and

    parm_key_1 in ( nvl(i_key_val(1),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_2 in ( nvl(i_key_val(2),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_3 in ( nvl(i_key_val(3),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_4 in ( nvl(i_key_val(4),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_5 in ( nvl(i_key_val(5),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_6 in ( nvl(i_key_val(6),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_7 in ( nvl(i_key_val(7),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_8 in ( nvl(i_key_val(8),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_9 in ( nvl(i_key_val(9),'*'), '*' , '**')  and
    parm_key_10 in (nvl(i_key_val(10),'*'),'*' , '**')
    order by  wild_card_ind  asc;
```

In the `IN( .. , .. , ..)` clause of above query, if the value of i_key_value(i) turns out to be not null, then it becomes like `(value, *, **).`

In case of not null, I want something like `( value )` only in `IN` clause, else `('*', '**')`

How to modify the query to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  The use of `decode()` suggests Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
...
and
((i_key_val(1) is not null and parm_key_1 in (i_key_val(1))) or parm_key_1 in ('*', '**'))
and
((i_key_val(2) is not null and parm_key_2 in (i_key_val(2))) or parm_key_2 in ('*', '**')) 
...
```

Or this;)

```
...
parm_key_1 in ( nvl(i_key_val(1),'*'), nvl(i_key_val(1),'**'))  and
...
```